# Pandas apply output includes the first row repeated len(df) times

Tags: python, pandas

I am officially at wits end with this, and at this point I'm hoping this has happened to someone else who knows what's happening. My pandas apply function seems to be corrupted, somehow...

Take a simple data frame:

```
data = [{'id':1,'val':2},{'id':3,'val':4},{'id':5,'val':6}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And let's create a nice simple function to apply:

```
def inc1(row):
    row['val2']=row['val']+1
    return row
```

If we do an `apply`...
`df.apply(inc1, axis=1)`
... we would expect (and do obtain on every other computer):

```
       id  val  val2
    0   1    2     3
    1   3    4     5
    2   5    6     7
```

But instead, on my laptop with this issue, we get:

```
   id  val  val2
0   1    2     3
1   1    2     3
2   1    2     3
```

It started with just the 3.8.5 installation, but has since *also* occurred in its 3.7.4 installation. Below is the pd.show_versions for 3.8.5. Does anyone have any idea what causes this?

```
>>> pd.show_versions()

 

INSTALLED VERSIONS

------------------

commit           : d9fff2792bf16178d4e450fe7384244e50635733

python           : 3.8.5.final.0

python-bits      : 64

OS               : Windows

OS-release       : 10

Version          : 10.0.18362

machine          : AMD64

processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

byteorder        : little

LC_ALL           : None

LANG             : None

LOCALE           : English_United States.1252

 

pandas           : 1.1.0

numpy            : 1.19.1

pytz             : 2020.1

dateutil         : 2.8.1

pip              : 20.2

setuptools       : 47.1.0

Cython           : 0.29.21

pytest           : None

hypothesis       : None

sphinx           : None

blosc            : None

feather          : None

xlsxwriter       : None

lxml.etree       : None

html5lib         : None

pymysql          : None

psycopg2         : None

jinja2           : 2.11.2

IPython          : 7.16.1

pandas_datareader: None

bs4              : None

bottleneck       : None

fsspec           : 0.7.4

fastparquet      : None

gcsfs            : None

matplotlib       : 3.3.0

numexpr          : None

odfpy            : None

openpyxl         : 3.0.4

pandas_gbq       : None

pyarrow          : None

pytables         : None

pyxlsb           : None

s3fs             : None

scipy            : 1.5.2

sqlalchemy       : 1.3.18

tables           : None

tabulate         : None

xarray           : None

xlrd             : 1.2.0

xlwt             : None

numba            : 0.50.1
```

Comment: It is working on my side ~

Comment: Yeah...I know this is like playing the wheel of fortune with the 1,000,000 option being 'find someone else who has managed to reproduce a problem that I can only reproduce on this one computer'

Comment: It works [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VfBRxlHpWDWAXjD1MF-yLpuWfNNtM32L?usp=sharing) as well.

Comment: How confident are you that you are running the same code on the machine which produces the wrong output?

Comment: Very, ran exact same .py file without modification -- quite fun isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here, please look at this code and output, It's working fine!]

On my pc, It's working, Please try again with same code, and look at your dataframe before compilation.

Comment: Yes, it works on all of my other PCs too, just not the one :/

Comment: Haha yeah it is 'awesome'! Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're using the same version of pd?

Try something like this, including different approach to initialization of the df

```py
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
  
# Creating the DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'], 
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000]}) 
  
# Print the dataframe 
print(df) 

df['Discounted_Price'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Cost - 
                                  (row.Cost * 0.1), axis = 1) 
    
# Print the dataframe with new column
print(df)
```

Example taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-existing-columns/)

Which in you case would simply become:

```py
df['val2'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.val + 1, axis = 1)
```

If the issue persists, I'd advise clean install of the python interpreter and the packages.

Comment: Thanks--my first time seeing apply used like that! Interestingly that *does* work. I know I'll have to reinstall the interpreter and packages, just having a small hope that we can figure out what happened in the first place

Comment: @ww2406 Try to pin the issue, multiple things here are different than in the original post. Check initialization, access to specific value, using lambda

Comment: So I changed the initialization to match the format above, no difference. As far as I can tell, changing to the lambda works under both initialization paradigms, but using the traditional apply does not work under either. Seems the primary difference is using a traditional apply function vs the method provided above.

Comment: Notice that the access to certain element is also different i.e. row.val vs row['val']. However, access via [] operator is proffered